# How to stop older service workers?

Tags: service-worker

The image below shows that there are two workers installed - one active and the other not active (just installed).

[image: two service workers running]

1. Register a service worker
2. Make changes to `service-worker.js` and reload the page.
3. The logic is that Service Workers check binary diff and updates the versions of the workers.

So a new service worker is spawned with a new version ID. But why does the old one keeps running ? and How do I close it ?

The `sw.js` is here https://gist.github.com/boopathi/57b7e8b6d657d55bdc7d

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default, until all tabs that have a page controlled by that old service worker are closed/unloaded, the old service worker will stay running. The new service worker will, well, "wait" in the "waiting" state.

There are options that change this default behavior. They're [`skipWaiting()`](https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/#service-worker-global-scope-skipwaiting) and [`clients.claim()`](https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/#clients-claim).

When `skipWaiting()` is called from an installing service worker, it will, well, skip the "waiting" state and immediately activate. However, it will not necessarily take control of pages despite being activated—that's what `clients.claim()` will accomplish.

Comment: The `skipWaiting()` and `clients.claim()` seems not to trigger the controllerchange event. I am currenty watching the course about SW - https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud899/ and I found that currently the only option is to leave the page and then come back. SkipWaiting did not work for me